# Appearance theme is only changing the color of applications

Tags: 18.04, gnome, themes, gnome-tweaks

I have the mojave gtk themes and whenever I use any of them, they change the color but not anything else with the apps. It also only shows the close tab button on the upper right corner. Was there something that I missed?

here is an example with the file manager
[image]

So, what can I do? Please tell me if I did not include everything you need to know or have anything questions, thanks.

Edit 1: I'm also on a chromebook

Comment: GNOME3 is not really designed to accommodate themes. They are there more as a vestige of older versions. GNOME devs deliberately designed GNOME3 to be consistent and easy-to-use at the expense of a million options and settings. If you want fine-tuned control over the appearance of your desktop, you are probably better off using another [flavor](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) like Kubuntu (KDE) or Xubuntu (Xfce), since these desktops are designed to allow significant customization out of the box. You can try a different flavor with a live session without affecting your installed system.

Comment: @Nmath Hi, I've grown recently to really hate xfce and I also believe it had the same issue too, I was using a different theme but it too was based off of MacOs and it had the same problem where, for example, only the exit button would show. How would I be able to try KDE on a live session? I'll try it tomorrow at school and see how it goes.

Comment: Download [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/) and flash it to a USB.  Boot from the USB and choose "Try Kubuntu". Canonical has a [tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) for creating a bootable USB stick. It suggests Startup Disk Creator, but personally I prefer [etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to flash the USB.

Comment: Would this work as expected on a chromebook (I assume yes)

Comment: If you can run Ubuntu Desktop you should be able to run Kubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme does what is does. If it only changes the color, then that is because the theme only does that. Probably, it is also changing the appearance of widgets such as selection boxes etc. Themes can also change some metrics (e.g. make title bars smaller, etc), but apparently the Mojave theme does not do that.

Indeed, Gnome Themes are an all or nothing thing. You apply them and they change all they are designed to change. The only way to change some individual aspect is to [edit source code](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358632/how-to-reduce-the-height-of-headerbar-titlebar-of-gtk3-apps-using-csd).

That a theme takes away minimize and maximize buttons is unexpected. That is not done by the actual theme. Perhaps, your mojave theme was installed using an install script, that then could have removed these buttons? Anyway, try restoring the minimize and maximize buttons with Gnome Tweaks, "Window Titlebars" tab.

Comment: The tab "Windows Titlebars" does not show on my Gnome-Tweaks

Comment: Nvm those options were in the Windows tab. I also moved those buttons to the left to achieve what I was looking for. Also, my mojave themes were installed by an install script so maybe that is what caused it. I'll mark this as an answer as it basically did solve my problem.

Comment: So my guess was right, about the install script. Strange move from the theme developpers: in MacOX, you have all three buttons anyway.